# How to extract all items from an HTML table with BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Here is the HTML that is part of a larger website that I am scraping.: https://pastebin.com/LZ3mJKv0

Basically I want my output to be:

```
Breed: Shih Tzu
Price: $850
Gender: Male
Nickname: Wade
Age: 16 Weeks Old
Color/Markings: red and white
Size at Maturity: Small
```

etc, etc. I have tried finding all tr tags, all td tags, and finding all b tags but none have given the output I am looking for or gave an error.

Thank you in advance for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(content, 'html.parser')
new_results = [[c.text.replace('\n', '') for c in i.find_all('td')] for i in d.find_all('tr')]
for i in new_results:
  print(' '.join(i))
```

Output:

```
Breed: Shih Tzu
Price: $850
Gender: Male Male
Nickname: Wade
Age: 16 Weeks Old
Color/Markings: red and white
Size at Maturity: Small
Availability Date: 08/01/2018
Shipping Area: Pick Up Only
Payment Method: Credit Cards, Cash
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but it pulls from other tables that I don't want that the full html has. Is there a way to only pull from a table that is in a certain class? The table that I want is contained in `<div> class="properties"> Or even simpler, just pull rows of with a specific title, like say if I only wanted the breed, price, and age? Thank you.